# How to fix problem with freezing sync - Gradle: Download maven-metadata.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying open project in Android Studio 4.0 and after I import it, Gradle sync starts, but it always ends in state "Gradle: Download maven-metadata.xml".

Is there any workaround for this?

Other projects are fine, whithout any problem. But I do not know how to find what cause this.

Comment: Maybe something got corrupted, try a invalidate & restart

Comment: @Elect I tried and it doesn´t help. Still same.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but killing the Charles app on my Mac seems like solved this. Check if you have any tool/proxy/VPN/firewall like this one that manipulates/listens/throttles your network calls.

You can also try turning on Gradle's offline mode but that won't really solve it (may solve temporarily) because it will fail if you are missing dependencies..